# Javascript setInterval and setTimeout giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a setInterval with an interval of 4 seconds , which is calling a function fun1. Now for the first Hi to print it is taking 16 seconds which is understandable but now after every 4 seconds I am seeing a "Hi".

Why there is a no delay of 16 seconds now? I am seeing that 12 second delay only once

```js
function fun1() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Hi");
  }, 12000);
}

setInterval(async() => {
  await fun1();
}, 4000);
```

I tried incrementing value of p every time , to check if fun1() is running only once but , the value is incrementing every time so why there is no delay now. I expect 16 seconds delay after every "Hi".

Comment: `fun1` does not return a Promise, so there's nothing to `await` so fun1 is executed every 4 seconds - even if it did return a Promise, fun1 would still be executed every 4 seconds because the setInterval would still run it every 4 seconds

Comment: put a console.log either side of `await fun1()` to see what is happening

Comment: Every 4 second you call `fun1`. Every call to `fun1` creates a new function that will be called 12 seconds into the future. So, the first "Gi" is printed after 4 + 12 = 16 seconds. The second after 4 + 4 + 12 = 20 seconds. The third after 24 seconds and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is happening?

When you start your program, `setInterval` is set to call `fun1()` every 4 seconds. However, in `fun1()`, you have a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) that waits for 12 seconds before printing "Hi". Therefore, for the first "Hi" to appear, it takes 4 seconds (for the first [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) call) + 12 seconds (`setTimeout` delay) = 16 seconds.

After the first call, `setInterval` continues to call `fun1()` every 4 seconds. However, each call to `fun1()` sets up a new `setTimeout` that will trigger 12 seconds later. This means that after the initial delay, there will be overlapping `setTimeout` calls.

- At 8 seconds (from the start), the second call to `fun1()` happens,
  setting up a `setTimeout` to print "Hi" at 20 seconds.
- At 12 seconds (from the start), the third call to `fun1()` happens,
  setting up a `setTimeout` to print "Hi" at 24 seconds.
- And so on.

So, after the first "Hi" at 16 seconds, every subsequent "Hi" comes from a `setTimeout` that was set up in a previous cycle of `setInterval`. This results in a new "Hi" appearing every 4 seconds, which is the interval of your `setInterval`, but offset by the initial 12-second delay from the `setTimeout`.

### How to fix it?

If you want a 16-second delay between each "Hi", you would need to ensure that `fun1()` does not get called again until after its `setTimeout` has been completed. This could be achieved by using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and [recursively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) calling `fun1()` at the end of the `setTimeout`:

```js
function fun1() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Hi");
    fun1(); // Recursively call fun1
  }, 16000);
}

fun1(); // Initial call to start the cycle
```